# Why does XPath exaluate gives snapshotLength = 1 for /html/body and 0 for /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div?

Tags: xpath, greasemonkey, document.evaluate

Could you tell me why XPath exaluate gives

```
  snapshotLength = 1 for /html/body
```

and 0 for

```
  /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div
```

The longer XPath is for real, calculated by Firepath for an object on this page

http://srv1.yogh.io/#mine:height:0

I run the following script in Greasemonkey.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        xpath greasemonkey
// @namespace   bbb
// @description f
// @match       http://srv1.yogh.io/#mine:height:0
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
var allLinks, thisLink;
console.log("dfsdsdsdfg");
allLinks = document.evaluate(
     "/html/body/div",
     document,
     null,
     XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
     null);
// for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.snapshotLength; i++) {
//   thisLink = allLinks.snapshotItem(i);
 // console.log("found");
// }
console.log(allLinks.snapshotLength)


// /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div
// ---
// UPDATED userscript

// ==UserScript==
// @name        xpath greasemonkey2
// @namespace   bbb
// @description f
// @match       http://srv1.yogh.io/#mine:height:0
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

window.setTimeout(function() {
  var allLinks, thisLink;
  console.log("dfsdsdsdfg");
   
  allLinks = document.evaluate(
       "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div",
       document,
       null,
       XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
       null);
  if(allLinks.snapshotLength) {
    console.log(allLinks.snapshotLength);
    console.log(allLinks.snapshotItem(0).innerHTML)
  } else {
    console.log("Bother...");
    console.log(allLinks.snapshotLength)
  }
}, 15000);

function myFunction() {
    if (window.top != window.self)  {
      alert("This window is not the topmost window! Am I in a frame?");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This window is not the topmost window! Am I in a frame?";
    } else { 
       alert("This window is the topmost window! Am I in a frame?");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This window is the topmost window!";
    } 
}
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="GreaseMonkey Button";
input.onclick = myFunction;
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

I would like the code to find the XPathed DIV object on web page
highlight it and return via console.log as:

```
<div class="gwt-Label">2083236893</div>
```

for postprocessing to read string 2083236893 via
       .innerText or .innerHTML

Any idea or any working script demo to work in GM or in Fiddle?

Comment: BTW, I inherited the above example from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762844/xpath-greasemonkey  I study great XPath Tutorial examples at http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html but have no tools to turn web page into alike tree nodes diagram

Comment: What is *"XPath exaluate"*? Do you mean *"XPath evaluate"*? Or perhaps *"XPath evaluation"*, given the context it is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is actually OK, and should work if you enter it directly in your browser's console.  The problem is that the content of the Blockchain web page is generated dynamically by a script, so the node you are looking for doesn't exist at the time your userscript is executed.

You need to delay your code from running until after the page has finished loading.  The [@run-at](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) userscript metadata directive is supposed to achieve this, but either it's broken in GreaseMonkey v4, or the Blockchain script takes too long time to run and you need to delay your userscript even longer.  Either way, wrapping your code in `setTimeout()` is a simple way to do the trick (detecting when the other script has finished would be more elegant):

```html
// ==UserScript==
// @name        xpath greasemonkey
// @namespace   bbb
// @description f
// @match       http://srv1.yogh.io/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

window.setTimeout(function() {
  var allLinks, thisLink;
  console.log("dfsdsdsdfg");
  allLinks = document.evaluate(
       "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div",
       document,
       null,
       XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
       null);
  if(allLinks.snapshotLength) {
    console.log(allLinks.snapshotItem(0).innerHTML);
  } else {
    console.log("Bother...");
  }
}, 5000);
```

(Note I also had to change your `@match` directive to get Greasemonkey to run the script on the right page).

Comment: Thank you @JRI for your excellent answer. I have slightly modified your script to console.log(allLinks.snapshotLength) since I got console.log("Bother..."); every time executed. At timeout increased to 15000 I get dfsdsdsdfg  
13  
dfsdsdsdfg  
Bother...  
0       .It looks like the script gets executed twice. Tested for http://srv1.yogh.io/#mine:height:0 dfsdsdsdfg  
2083236893 ...downloadable font: download failed.. dfsdsdsdfg  
Bother...  
0 It looks like allLinks.snapshotLength gets modified from 1 to 0

Comment: follow-up your script slightly modified for more consol.log s timeout set to 15000 and script gets executed twice in GM3.17 , the one working for FirefoxESR 52.2.1 32-bit.      dfsdsdsdfg  xpath_greasemonkey2.user.js:12:3
1  xpath_greasemonkey2.user.js:21:5
2083236893  xpath_greasemonkey2.user.js:22:5
dfsdsdsdfg  xpath_greasemonkey2.user.js:12:3
Bother...  xpath_greasemonkey2.user.js:24:5
0  xpath_greasemonkey2.user.js:25:5     What makes the GM script to be executed twice and for the second time allLinks.snapshotLength switches from 1 to 0 ?

Comment: The script only runs once for me in GM4.1 or Tampermonkey v4.4.  If it runs twice, it may be running on an IFrame as well as the main web page.  The snapshotLength is only 1 in the main page, because the IFrame won't have the same structure.  You can check for this by testing if (window.self !== window.top).

Comment: I have appended  if (window.top != window.self) input.value="GreaseMonkey Button"; and  else { 
       alert("This window is the topmost window! Am I in a frame?"); closed console and get the above message on button click. Not sure why script code is executed immediately, not waiting 15000ms window.setTimeout(function() {  I get allLinks = document.evaluate( immediately calculated and Greasemonkey button appears on top at the same time, not wating 15000.  Not sure how to delay allLinks = document.evaluate(  if window.setTimeout(function()

Comment: BTW appended updated script to snippet above for review by you

Comment: follow-up Tampermonkey version=4.5.5660 installed for Firefox 52.2.1 32-bit. Script installed, enabled, TM enabled and script not run: No script is running.  TM FAQ http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php?version=4.5.5660&ext=fire#Q101 is all about TM configuration in Chrome. Is Firefox not supported ? "Go to Chromes extension page ..."

Comment: Thank you @JRI for your best answer. I need to ask developers of Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey why your excellent code solution fails to work properly for me, making the myscript code to be executed 2 or 3 .times.

Comment: Greasemonkey is executing userscript not waiting for full HTML document download, so depending on the load time, you can get random results, as in this case.